# Google sheets scripting - getting the actual range for a copy/paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I'm writing myself a little script to help me with some dataValidation and I've encountered an issue:

Given a range of 10 rows and 1 column, I select at least 2 of those rows and copy and then paste it somewhere else in the sheet and I get something like this as feedback through Logger.log:

```
[18-08-31 14:15:32:677 PDT] coverage rows[1.0-3.0] cols[5.0-5.0]
```

Printed by:

```
curRange = e.range;
var minRow = curRange.getRow();
var maxRow = curRange.getLastRow();
var minCol = curRange.getColumn();
var maxCol = curRange.getLastColumn();
Logger.log("rows[%s-%s] cols[%s-%s]", minRow, maxRow, minCol, maxCol);
```

Now... the odd part is: if I have a filter on the said column and I select to display only 1 value I'll end up with let's say 4 rows (ID's 2, 5, 6 and 8). If I perform a copy of this smaller Range (4 rows and 1 column) and then paste it somewhere else in the sheet, I'll get the following feedback:

```
[18-08-31 14:15:32:677 PDT] coverage rows[2.0-2.0] cols[5.0-5.0]
```

Is there any way through onEdit(e) { e.range } to figure out which ID's I have edited? Or any other solution that would bring me the values 2, 5, 6 and 8?

Comment: [tag:google-sheets-api] could be used with [tag:google-apps-script] when the script is using the Spreadsheet Advanced Services.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to just use this in the comment, but it's too messed up there. So I will write an answer instead.

`onEdit(e)` only trigger if you edit a range, and `e` is the range that's edited. So if you paste the data, you will trigger `onEdit(e)` with `e` is your destination, and the source range is "forgotten" for good. Using `onEdit(e)`, there's no way to know what you have done before you trigger it. Hence, you cannot write anything to your log prior to before `onEdit(e)` triggered.. in this case, the range that you've copied the data.

Here's a little trick to do what you need : copy & paste using script. Write a function with something like this

```
for(i = r;i < r + numRow ;i++) {
    if (sheet.getRange("A" + i) matches filter) {// assume that you filter your data based on column A
    copy data to destination
    write source to log
    } 
 }
```

and then assign that function somewhere on your sheet.

Each time you need to do your work, you only need to run your function.

While there are also other way to achieve what you want, that is to write out the number of row in one column using `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A1000))`, and when you copy the data, copy that column too, then you can process those value as if you're working with the row number in your code. Well, this is sloppy and you might have to edit the formula from time to time when your sheet expand more than 1000 rows .. which is why I don't recommend it. But if you can predict how many row is good for your sheet, i guess it's okay..